# json_decode returns NULL over $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm having trouble working out things with json_decode. I got a valid json that's being sent over $_POST.

Here's the JSON object that is being passed, the inventory variable:

```
[{"item_name":"Screw Driver","item_desc":"asdasd","item_type":"weapon"},
{"item_name":"Brown Shoes","item_desc":"asdasd","item_type":"footwear"}]
```

Here's the html javascript code.

```
<form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method = "post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type = "hidden" name = "inv" id = "inv"/>
    <input type = "submit" id = "btn_save" onclick = "saveInventory()" value = "Save"/>
</form>

<script type = "text/javascript">
function saveInventory(){
    var inv = document.getElementById("inv");
    inv.value = inventory;
}
</script>
```

Here's the php script that'll fetch the json from input type hidden

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['inv'])){
    $inv = $_POST['inv'];
    var_dump(json_decode($inv,true)); // returns NULL
}
?>
```

I've been reading lots of json_decode issues over the web but most of them have different issues regarding json_decode returning null. Anyone might find out what's wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: the form submission executes before the javascript add value to your field.

Comment: First do a `var_dump()` on $inv before you do the `json_decode()` to check you have somthing in there. Then try adding this to your <form... tag `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: @RoyalBg What? Are you sure? Its called from `onclick` is it not?

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is, but why do you think the onclick operation happens before the submit operation? I would be OK for that, if there was not SUBMIT type, but the javascript, after appending value, does `form1.submit`. Input type button with onclick event, where the js handles the submission will execute first the value appending then the submission.

Comment: yep, I tried using var dump it returns NULL, I added enctype="multipart/form-data" still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your `inventory` variable is a JavaScript array of objects, instead of a JSON string. So you need to convert it to JSON to store it in the HTML input value:

```
function saveInventory(){
    var inv = document.getElementById("inv");
    inv.value = JSON.stringify(inventory); // convert to JSON string
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thought it was not working at first cause I did that once, turned out I need to resend data.

JSON.stringify - is the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['inv'])){
        $json=json_decode($_POST['inv']);
        foreach($json as $j){
            echo "NAME: ".$j->{"item_name"};
            echo "<hr/>";
        }
    }
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>">
    <input type="text" name='inv' value='[{"item_name":"Screw Driver","item_desc":"asdasd","item_type":"weapon"},{"item_name":"Brown Shoes","item_desc":"asdasd","item_type":"footwear"}]'/>
    <input type="submit" value="SEND"/>
</form>
```